# Query about tensorlfow keras learning rate?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm implementing deep architecture using TensorFlow Keras. At first, I used a loss function without defining the learning rate, for example:

```
 model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I'm wondering as to what the default learning rate is and how TensorFlow Keras sets it. Second, which is preferable: the default-specified learning rate or the Custom (user-specified) learning rate?

Then I switched to a custom learning rate. However, I've observed two different approaches of assigning a value to learning rate. For instance, one is **lr** and the other is **learning_rate**.

**first way to set learing rate**

```
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

**Second way to set learning rate**

```
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])
```

What is the difference between `learning_rate` and `lr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lr` implementation is deprecated but they essentially did the same thing. You can check this [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4dfb8d1a71385bd6d122e4f27f86dcebb96712d/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L834). Credit - @[Frightera.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13726668/frightera)

Comment: are you sure `lr` is not a parameter and is ignored?

Comment: Yes it helped, I deleted my misleading answer, and upvoted. Thank You!

Comment: It was used actually, now deprecated. Check [L373](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4dfb8d1a71385bd6d122e4f27f86dcebb96712d/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L373) and [L834](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4dfb8d1a71385bd6d122e4f27f86dcebb96712d/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L834).

Comment: @Frightera Thanks. I didn't saw it in the docs so I thought that it's incorrect. I will change my answer.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat thank you for the response. How about my first question?

Comment: @Ahmad The default learning rate is `0.001` when calling the `optimizer` using the `name`  TensorFlow loads the Optimizer with that name with default parameters and you can see the default parameters of Adam https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more thing, when we give data to model.fit, in Epochs its shows e.g 112/700, it means fit API divided the training data on batch size and that is showing 700 there?

Comment: @Ahmad That 700 is the `steps_per_epoch` and yes it is indeed as you said. i.e. `len(dataset)//batch_size`